# How do I convert RGB decimal to Hex colors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, colors, converters, rgb

I have RGB colors in the form:

```
[0.00784, 0.62745, 0.77647]
```

I would like to convert them to hex color, but I'm not sure how. I've seen other types of RGB components converted to hex, but not in this format.

Comment: Is it just a normalized version from 0 to 1? If so just `*255` and do a [rgb to hex conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply all the values by 255, round it and then use the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb).

```js
const componentToHex = c => {
  const hex = c.toString(16)
  return hex.length === 1 ? '0' + hex : hex
}

const rgbToHex = (r, g, b) => '#' + [r, g, b].map(componentToHex).join('')

const rgb = [0.00784, 0.62745, 0.77647].map(x => Math.round(x * 255))
console.log(rgbToHex(...rgb))
```